# Как суммировать значения словаря, у которого ключи - это даты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, словари, dict

Как суммировать значения словаря, у которого ключи - это даты?

Cуммировать нужно только те значения, ключи которых в сумме не более 7-ми дней.

```py
d = {'2020-10-04': 9, 
     '2020-10-05': 6, 
     '2020-10-07': 3, 
     '2020-10-10': 3, 
     '2020-10-20': 6}
```

Comment: Семи дней - опишите точнее, что вы хотите. Попадают в неделю, например? Или как?

Comment: например: сумма значений {'2020-10-04': 9, '2020-10-05': 6,  '2020-10-07': 3, '2020-10-10': 3} - в пределах семи дней (не обязательно одной недели) равна 21; '2020-10-20': 6 - не суммируется т.к. вне диапазона 7 дней для предыдущих дат.

Comment: а например , если бы был ключ 2020-10-13, как это все делить на группы?

Comment: вот я и пытаюсь понять как делить ключи на группы, чтобы эта группа включала в себя только даты/ключи в пределах 7 дней от первого ключа в группе.

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-datetime-python/klass-timedelta-modulja-datetime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import datetime as DT

def str_to_date(string):
    return DT.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d').date()


_dict = {'2020-10-04': 9, 
     '2020-10-05': 6, 
     '2020-10-07': 3, 
     '2020-10-10': 3, 
     '2020-10-20': 6,
}
delta = DT.timedelta(days=7)

summs = []
keys = sorted(_dict.keys())
idx = 0
while keys:
    summs.append(0)
    date = str_to_date(keys[0])
    while keys and (str_to_date(keys[0]) - date < delta):
        summs[idx] += _dict[keys.pop(0)]
    idx += 1
print(summs)
```